# Cannot run node executable with #!/usr/bin/env node

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to write my own npm executable, but on installing the dependency in another project when I try and run the executable I see the error

```
$ node_modules/.bin/html-linter    
: No such file or directory
```

The file does exist and has the node shebang at the top (I copied exactly what the tslint executable had)

If I call it like

```
$ node node_modules/.bin/html-linter
```

It works perfectly, but I don't want to have to do that

My executable just looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

require('../lib/html-linter-cli');
```

The path is fine, if I run /usr/bin/env node in my console it works, if I run node --version I get a normal output.

If you want to install the package from npm you can, it is called html-linter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the full error message (which is unfortunately being obscured in your Terminal):

```
$ node_modules/.bin/html-linter
env: node\r: No such file or directory
```

The `\r` means you have a carriage return in the shebang line, likely due to Windows-style line endings (in your case, this character caused your Terminal to restart the line, overwriting part of the error and making it harder to see). The `file` command confirms this.

```
$ file node_modules/.bin/html-linter
node_modules/.bin/html-linter: a /usr/bin/env node script text executable, ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Solution: Don't use Windows line endings (pretty much ever) and save your files with Unix-style LF endings. Any decent code editor should have this option.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much